# using the hash sign in a query string in a link

Tags: php

I have a "next" button on my site with the code...

```
<a href="example.php?action=next#mark" ><img src="images/next-button6.png" class="button"/></a>
```

The hash sign is supposed to take it to a specific part of the page after the "next" action takes place. (the next action goes to the next blog post in the $_SESSION array)

Everything works great without the hash, but with the hash it just goes to the part of the page without actually refreshing the page.

Is this normal? If so, how do you get around it?

UPDATE:

Excellent info guys. I used the following workaround.

```
if ($_GET["x"]==1) $x = "&amp;x=0";
    else $x = "&amp;x=1";
```

THen I just add $x to the end of the link (before putting the #mark). Simple, but it works!

Comment: yes it is normal, if the link is to the page that it is currently on. if the `#mark` content is already on the page, im not sure why you would want to reload

Comment: well that's a useful comment ;)

Comment: @Dagon is correct again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior and it's what those hashes (or ['fragment identifiers'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)) are intended for.

Over the course of time they have been used (abused) to change the url in web applications and AJAX enriched pages, so the scripts on the page could use them as a bookmark, to remember which part of the page to show (or load) when the user was navigating back and forth through the history. 
The reason they used this fragment identifier, is because it used to be the only part of the url you could change without forcing a redirect to the new url.

Eventually this work-around was made obsolete by the introduction of the `pushState` and `popState` methods in the [history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), but still the hash is used sometimes for backwards compatibility.

So I think that's were your confusion may come from.

Anyway, it is supposed to work like this. If you don't want this, either use a different character than the `#` sign, or use JavaScript to force reloading the page by setting `location.href` or calling `location.reload()`. Note that since the fragment identifier is not (or not always) sent to the server, so don't rely on it in your server side script, so even when using JavaScript, you still have to put the relevant information in another part of the url. best solution, I think: use the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to send such information to the server.

Even when using query string or JavaScript, you can still add a `#` fragment, so the browser knows which part to jump to after it loads the new page.

Comment: What is the alternative to using the # sign? That is, directing the user to a specific part of the next page.

Comment: You can use the hash sign to send them to the specific part, but you need a different url as well, otherwise the page is not loaded, so I'd use the query string or a combination of query string and `#`. You've done that already, but if the query string is always `action=next`, the browser doesn't see the change. Make it `post=3` for instance, so you can have a different number each time, or `post=Title+of+the+blog` so you navigate to the (ever changing) title of the next post.